# Trying to define functions, but I get "List Function has no attributes"

Tags: python, list, function

```
def Bubble(L):
    x = L.copy()
    for j in range(len(x)):
        for i in range (len(x)-1):
            firstnumber = x[i]
            secondnumber = x[i+1]
            if x[i] > x[i+1]:
                x[i] = secondnumber
                x[i+1] = firstnumber
    return x

def Max(L):
    print(L.Bubble[len(L)-1])

def Min(L):
    print(L.Bubble[0])
```

I am trying to define Maximum and Minimum of a list after sorting the list with Bubble, but every time I run it, I get:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'Bubble'
```

Comment: Evidently `L` is a list. `Bubble` is a *function*, not a list method. It's unclear why you expected otherwise.

Comment: You'll need to check up on some of the basics. You're calling Bubble like it's a property on L, which it isn't - it's a function you've just defined yourself. You're accessing Bubble with `[]`, that won't work either, for a function. And finally, bubble sorting an entire copy of a list just to get a min or a max has to be the most inefficient way I've ever seen min or max implemented...

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`).  Your question should also include the code that produces the error. Please read [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This is related to object oriented programming.The member function of the object are encapsulated by the object and the way to access is them is `nameofobject.memberfunction(parameters if any)` . Here you defined a function which works on a list and not a member function of list hence this problem. The right way is :

```
Print(Bubble(L))
```

Comment: Except that `Bubble` has been defined as a function with a bad (capitalised) name, so I think OP has a few more problems to deal with.